# AngularJS - multiple ng-click - event bubbling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

In the following example:

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showItem(item)">
    <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    <button ng-click="remove(item)">Remove</button>
  </li>
```

When I click on the button `showItem()` also is invoked due to event bubbling.
I know that I can use `$event` to watch for `$event.currentTarget` and do `$event.stopPropagation()` etc. but this is very ugly.

Btw. I don't want to stop propagation on the `button` (In my case the `button` is a `twitter bootstrap` `dopdown/button` - this is just an example)

**How do I stop `showItem()` from beeing called when I click on the `remove` button?**

**EDIT**
The ugly fix would be to have:

```
function remove(item,$event){
  $event.originalEvent.prevent = true;
  // rest of the code
}

function showItem(item,$event){
  if($event.originalEvent.prevent)return;
  // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: If you can't use stopPropagation, you will have to restructure your dom so they're not nested. Is that possible?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This solution worked for me (I'm only supporting recent browsers, so I tried to modify the code to be more retro-compatible):

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showItem(item)">
    <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    <button ng-click="remove(item, $event)">Remove</button>
</li>
```

Scripts:

```
function remove(item, $event) {
    // do some code here

    // Prevent bubbling to showItem.
    // On recent browsers, only $event.stopPropagation() is needed
    if ($event.stopPropagation) $event.stopPropagation();
    if ($event.preventDefault) $event.preventDefault();
    $event.cancelBubble = true;
    $event.returnValue = false;
}
function showItem(item) {
    // code here
}
```

**EDIT** - Added a JSFiddle demo to try it out
http://jsfiddle.net/24e7mapp/1/

Comment: This method didn't work for me on Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153 m, but $event.stopPropagation() did.  I didn't need the $event.returnValue.

Comment: Exactly. In Chrome (and other modern browsers), you can stop at the first line: `$event.stopPropagation();` (without the 'if'). But as specified in the comments, if you need to make it work in IE8 et less, you have to use `$event.preventDefault()` or the `cancelBuble/returnValue`. Maybe one of those two aren't required, I can't remember exactly.

Comment: @Ron, please check out the demo and try it on different browser versions.

Comment: Both `$event.cancelBubble = true;` and `$event.returnValue = false;` breaks Chome/ium (tested on 43.0.2357.130).

Comment: @arcol You could simply to a check before, like so: `if ($event.cancelBubble) { $event.cancelBubble = true; }`.

Comment: @Tibo Why setting cancelBubble true when it already evaluates to true (otherwise the condition won't be ever satisfied).

Comment: @cepharum Sorry, you're right, I wrote it too fast. Should have been: `if (typeof $event.cancelBubble === 'boolean') $event.cancelBubble = true;`
BTW, this has no effect on Chrome 58 and Opera 45 (see [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelBubble#Browser_compatibility))

Answer (score 0):

`showItem` can be updated to return early if the passed in `item` no longer exists:

```
function remove(item) {
  if (-1 == $scope.items.indexOf(item)) {
    // Item no longer exists, return early
    return;
  }
  // Rest of code here
}
```