# Deactivating ui-sref on Button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, event-handling, event-bubbling

i'm using templates for a netbanking app (project at university) and try to implement a delete button for the templates.
Each list element is a button itself and changes the view on clicking one list element. Inside i repeatedly constructed a delete button.
The problem is, that each time i click the delete button, the view changes as well - is there any simple ng-click for instance, that deactivates the ui-sref when the delete button is clicked?

```
  <div ng-model="chosentemplate">
  <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="template in Templatelist" ng-model="choosetemplate" ui-sref="tab.transactions({params:template.iban})">
              <img ng-src="img/{{template.image}}">
              <h2><b>{{template.name}}</b></h2>

              <p ><b>IBAN</b> {{template.iban}}</p>
              <button ng-if="deletePress" ng-click="deleteTemplates($index)" ng-model="deletethistemplate" class="button button-small button-assertive">
                  Löschen
              </button>

  </a>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: prevent the event bubling by injecting as `deleteTemplates($index, $event)` and `$event.preventDefault()` inside the method.

Comment: Adding another parameter in the deleteTemplate may create trouble or where do you try to put this $event parameter to? 
DeleteTemplates is a function with .splice to delete an element?
I'm not sure, what you mean with preventDefault() :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - multiple ng-click - event bubbling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701092/angularjs-multiple-ng-click-event-bubbling)